# Telerik Test Studio - input text disappear immediately

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, telerik-test-studio

In my test studio automation test case for a web page, I have a test step which is simply input some text into a text box. The problem is the text disappear right after inputting.

Same situation would occur when I use Selenium Webdriver in C#.

Have you ever met this before? Please give me some help.

Answer (score 0):

In selenium use IJavaScriptExecutor class to set Text box value .If it doesn't work try clicking an element out of the text box after entering text box value.

Comment: I am currently using Telerik Test Studio not Selenium so I only tried your second solution. So far it works fine in a few cases but I need to observe more test cases in the future. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

In Test Studio try focusing on the text box element (you can do that by clicking on the element) and use the following code for typing the text:

```
Manager.Desktop.KeyBoard.TypeText("your text here", 50);
```